# Navigating Screens - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I created a simple Android app that changes navigates when the text is pressed. The app runs properly but when I touch the text, the contents do not change and no navigation is observed. You can have a look at the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzlfm.png). I have also provided the code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Navigator, Text, TouchableHighlight, View, AppRegistry} from 
'react-native';

export default class SimpleNavigationApp extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    title: 'My Initial Scene',
  }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ title: 'My Initial Scene', index: 0 }}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
          <MyScene
            title={route.title}

            // Function to call when a new scene should be displayed
            onForward={ () => {
              const nextIndex = route.index + 1;
              navigator.push({
                title: 'Scene ' + nextIndex,
                index: nextIndex,
              });
            }}

            // Function to call to go back to the previous scene
            onBack={() => {
              if (route.index > 0) {
                navigator.pop();
              }
            }}
          />
        }
      />
    )
  }
}

class dhrumil extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onForward: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onBack: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Current Scene: { this.props.title }</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onForward}>
          <Text>Tap me to load the next scene</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onBack}>
          <Text>Tap me to go back</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("dhrumil",()=>dhrumil);
```

As you can see in the error, the title is also not displayed after the text "My Current Scene: ". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

**First**, your export default class SimpleNavigationApp is never called.

You should put it in another js file and import it to dhrumil class

.

**Second**,
    import { Navigator } from 'react-native' is no longer supported.

Read https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html for detailed navigation documentation.